# Opacity not working on header div

Tags: html, css, opacity

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/sZaxc/17/embedded/result/)

I am trying to make the div `#top` `opacity: 50%`, so when you scroll, it will show a faded portion of the webpage below it. When I run this, however, it does not show opacity. It still shows solid.

CSS:

```
#top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #96f226;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #252525;
  position: relative;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 50%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='top'>Cuisine List</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`opacity` takes a decimal between 0 and 1, like so:

```
opacity: 0.5;
```

[See MDN for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity).

Also,

- you seem to have two `position`s - you should remove the first one
- for `position: fixed` to work, you must specify at least one location, such as:

  ```
  top: 0px;
  ```

  which will anchor it to the top.

[fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sZaxc/20/)

Comment: 1+ Beat me to it.. again.. although I don't think this will do what the OP wants, as they said something about fading on scroll.. Seems like they are looking for a JS solution of some sort.

Comment: @JoshC ;) The OP seems to have `position: fixed`, so I will edit to clarify

Comment: I have experimented with your answer, and found that you don't need to take the `position: fixed` out. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/sZaxc/21/)

Comment: @JJP I meant to take the `position: relative` out. Why is it there anyway?

Comment: I don't know. I think I asked a question about it being fixed, and the answer was that. but it seems to work fine without it...hmmmm